# Invalid usage of a reserved method name unlink() Sugar7

Tags: sugarcrm

I am having this problem related sugar7 Package installation [Invalid usage of reserved method SugarAutoLoader::unlink()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p2CD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just found a helpful link https://github.com/maranemil/howto/blob/master/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_ondemand_alternative_functions.txt  and it tells us how to use blacklist function .... Here we can find unlink() method also.

Invalid usage of a remove file / dir

```
# before
unlink(....)

# after
//SugarAutoloader::unlink($filename);
//require_once("include/dir_inc.php");
//rmdir_recursive($filename);

require_once("include/upload_file.php");
$us = new UploadStream();
$us->unlink($filename);
```